# How to perform opposite of LISTAGG in Oracle

Tags: oracle

I have a table named "Table1".

[image: Given Table]

Now, how to write a query so that all comma separated values are represented  separately in new row

The output would look something like below table

[image: Resultant Table]

I know about `listagg` but i don't have any idea about how to do the opposite of what I mentioned above.

Comment: Check the duplicate link for a number of approaches.  This question gets asked at least once per day on this site.

Comment: Yes, I would say more than once. Storing comma separated values in a relational table was a bad design decision which is going to haunt  people for years to come. Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad) to know more why it's bad.